# Derive $|s_n - s| \lt \frac{|s|}{2} \implies |s_n| \gt \frac{|s|}{2}$ algebraically

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$\{s_n\}$ is an infinite sequence of complex numbers.

How do I derive this inequality algebraically? It makes intuitive sense, however.

This appears in Baby Rudin’s theorem 3.3(d): [Theorem 3.3 (d) Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463974/theorem-3-3-d-rudin)

Comment: You did not type the inequality correctly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: $|s| \leq |s_n-s|+|s_n| <\frac {|s|} 2+|s_n|$. Transfer the first term on RHS to  LHS.

Comment: The inequality is still not the one in the book. Copy it carefully from the book.

Comment: Ah! Sorry about that. Fixed it for good now, I hope. Thank you for your response.

Comment: reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: Yes, @JackyChong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|s| - |s_n| \leq |s_n - s|$ by the triangle inequality. Then

$|s| - |s_n| \leq |s_n - s| < \frac{|s|}{2}$

$\frac{|s|}{2} < |s_n|$

Comment: Just fleshing out the first part, since it wasn't obvious to me: $|s-s_n+s_n|\leq |s-s_n|+|s_n|\Rightarrow |s|\leq |s-s_n|+|s_n|$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{|s|}2 &= |s|-\frac{|s|}2 \\
&= |(s-s_n)+s_n|-\frac{|s|}2 \\
&\leq |s-s_n|+|s_n|-\frac{|s|}2 \qquad (\textrm{triangle inequality: }|a+b|\leq|a|+|b|)  \\
&= |s_n-s|+|s_n|-\frac{|s|}2 \qquad (\textrm{because }|a-b|=|b-a|) \\
&< \frac{|s|}2+|s_n|-\frac{|s|}2 = |s_n|.
\end{align}